# tSQLt - Test that a column is output by a stored procedure

Tags: tsqlt

I'm very new to tSQLt and am having some difficulty with what should really be a very simple test.

I have added a column to the SELECT statement executed within a stored procedure.

How do I test in a tSQLt test that the column is included in the resultset from that stored procedure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, when adding a column to the output of a stored procedure, you will want to test that the column both exists and is populated with the correct data. Since we're going to make sure that the column is populated with the same data, we can design a test that does exactly that:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyTests.[test stored procedure values MyNewColumn correctly]
AS
BEGIN
  -- Create Actual and Expected table to hold the actual results of MyProcedure 
  -- and the results that I expect
  CREATE TABLE MyTests.Actual (FirstColumn INT, MyNewColumn INT);
  CREATE TABLE MyTests.Expected (FirstColumn INT, MyNewColumn INT);

  -- Capture the results of MyProcedure into the Actual table
  INSERT INTO MyTests.Actual
  EXEC MySchema.MyProcedure;

  -- Create the expected output
  INSERT INTO MyTests.Expected (FirstColumn, MyNewColumn)
  VALUES (7, 12);
  INSERT INTO MyTests.Expected (FirstColumn, MyNewColumn)
  VALUES (25, 99);


  -- Check that Expected and Actual tables contain the same results
  EXEC tSQLt.AssertEqualsTable 'MyTests.Expected', 'MyTests.Actual';
END;
```

Generally, the stored procedure you are testing relies on other tables or other stored procedures. Therefore, you should become familiar with FakeTable and SpyProcedure as well: http://tsqlt.org/user-guide/isolating-dependencies/

Comment: Thanks Dennis. I think I was trying to over complicate the issue by concentrating on the one new column but by testing the procedure's output that column will be tested by default

Answer (score 1):

Another option if you are just interested in the structure of the output and not the content (and you are running on SQL2012 or greater) would be to make use of `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object` in your test.

This dmo (dynamic management object) returns a variety of information about the first result set returned for a given object.

In my example below, I have only used a few of the columns returned by this dmo but others are available if, for example, your output includes decimal data types.

In this test, I populate a temporary table (`#expected`) with information about how I expect each column to be returned - such as name, datatype and nullability.

I then select the equivalent columns from the dmo into another temporary table (`#actual`).

Finally I use `tSQLt.AssertEqualsTable` to compare the contents of the two tables.

Having said all that, whilst I frequently write tests to validate the structure of views or tables (using `tSQLt.AssertResultSetsHaveSameMetaData`), I have never found the need to just test the result set contract for procedures.  Dennis is correct, you would typically be interested in asserting that the various columns in your result set are populated with the correct values and by the time you've covered that functionality you should have covered every column anyway.

```
if object_id('dbo.myTable') is not null drop table dbo.myTable;
go
if object_id('dbo.myTable') is null
begin
    create table dbo.myTable
    (
      Id int not null primary key
    , ColumnA varchar(32) not null
    , ColumnB varchar(64) null
    )
end
go
if object_id('dbo.myProcedure') is not null drop procedure dbo.myProcedure;
go
create procedure dbo.myProcedure
as
begin
    select Id, ColumnA, ColumnB from dbo.myTable;
end
go

exec tSQLt.NewTestClass @ClassName = 'myTests';

if object_id('[myTests].[test result set on SQL2012+]') is not null drop procedure [myTests].[test result set on SQL2012+];
go
create procedure [myTests].[test result set on SQL2012+]
as
begin
    ; with expectedCte (name, column_ordinal, system_type_name, is_nullable)
    as
    (
        -- The first row sets up the data types for the #expected but is excluded from the expected results
                  select cast('' as nvarchar(200)), cast(0 as int), cast('' as nvarchar(200)), cast(0 as bit)
        -- This is the result we are expecting to see
        union all select 'Id', 1, 'int', 0
        union all select 'ColumnA', 2, 'varchar(32)', 0
        union all select 'ColumnB', 3, 'varchar(64)', 1
    )
    select * into #expected from expectedCte where column_ordinal > 0;

    --! Act
    select
          name
        , column_ordinal
        , system_type_name
        , is_nullable
    into
        #actual
    from
        sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object(object_id('dbo.myProcedure'), 0);

    --! Assert
    exec tSQLt.AssertEqualsTable '#expected', '#actual';
end
go
exec tSQLt.Run '[myTests].[test result set on SQL2012+]'
```

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed reply but unfortunately we're still using 2008 R2 for this project.